# Ending a 302 redirect and its effect on Pagerank

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, pagerank, 302-redirect

Please imagine the following scenario:

`abc.com` → 302 (temporary) redirect to `def.com`
After 6 months, we no longer use `def.com`, so discard the domain and we buy a new domain `xyz.com`.

We then do a 302 redirect from `abc.com` to `xyz.com`.

Firstly, would `abc.com` show up back on Google (temporarily, once we delete the 302 redirect)?

And secondly, would this mean `def.com` would disappear and `xyz.com` would appear instead of it?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, def.com would eventually disappear from the index.

Depending on how long you wait, though, abc.com might not show back up again. Google will generally crawl a 302 redirect much less often than a regularly changing page.

If you did exactly what you are proposing, it's theoretically possible that def.com, abc.com *and* xyz.com could be out of the index for an amount of time.

What I would recommend doing at this stage, to cover all your bases, is to:

- 301 from abc.com to xyz.com
- 301 from def.com to xyz.com (i.e. keep def.com registered and active for a bit)

This is because you have no way of knowing whether Google has started directly crawling def.com, and it'd be a pity to effectively tell Google the site is offline until it happens to find it again via one of the other two URLs.

Comment: Yes would definitely do a 301 from def to xyz however, if keep up the whitehat seo works and keep working on domain abc, would that not keep abc indexed ongoingly even though there is a 302 to def.com? This is provided we do not do SEO work for def, and it will be solely for abc.com